# How can I show that $\mathbb{E}(Y|\sigma(X))$ satisfies the abstract definition of conditional expectation?

Tags: stochastic-analysis

More precisely let $(X,Y)$ is a pair of continuous random variables with joint density function $f(x,y)$ and we assume $\mathbb{E}(|Y|) < +\infty$. Define
$$H(X) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}y dy,$$
where $f_X(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) dy$.

For $H(X)$ to satisfy the definition we have to show that

- $\mathbb{E}(|H(X)|) < +\infty$,
- $H(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable and
- $\mathbb{E}(Y \cdot I_A) = \mathbb{E}(H(X) \cdot I_A)$, for every $A \in \sigma(X)$, where $I_A$ is the indicator of $A$.

This is a homework assignment for me, so I only need some hints, not a full solution.

Comment: The second property you want to show is rather obvious. $x \mapsto H(x)$ is continuous. So you have composition of two measurable mappings: $\omega \mapsto X(\omega) \mapsto H(X(\omega))$

Comment: Not sure if this would be the right way but for the last property you could perhaps use a $\pi-\lambda$ argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint on third bullet:

On base of $H\left(x\right)f_{X}\left(x\right)=\int f\left(x,y\right)ydy$
we find for suitable functions $g$:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[H\left(X\right)g\left(X\right)\right]=\int H\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)f_{X}\left(x\right)dx=\int\int f\left(x,y\right)yg\left(x\right)dydx=\mathbb{E}\left[Yg\left(X\right)\right]$$

Comment: This really helped, thanks. Could you also tell me what makes a function $g$ suitable?

Comment: It must be a Borelmeasurable function such that the expectation of $H(X)g(X)$ exists. If the expectation of $H(X)$ exists then it is enough if $g$ is measurable and bounded, so then it can be applied on functions like $1_A$.

Comment: You are very welcome.